# pinecone : Can I get all data(all vector) from a pinecone index? (to move data into another ID's index)

Tags: python

I have to move data from old account to new one. (Both are free account)

And there is 12,000 vectors at the index.

Is there any API or UI for pinecone to export "all" data?

### #1

I tried to get all data by using `top_k` as all number of my index...

```
query_embedding = embedder.encode('hi', convert_to_numpy=True)
response = index.query(query_embedding, top_k=12000, include_metadata=True)
```

But fail like below. the maximum return value is 10,000

```
ApiValueError: Invalid value for `top_k`, must be a value less than or equal to `10000`
```

### #2

https://docs.pinecone.io/reference/create_collection

I know there is the method that create new collection, but it seems that I can't access the other account's collection.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have saved id of vectors separately the next best thing to my knowledge is following

```
import numpy as np
def get_ids_from_query(index, input_vector):
    print("searching pinecone...")
    results = index.query(vector=input_vector,
                          top_k=10000, include_values=False)
    ids = set()
    print(type(results))
    for result in results['matches']:
        ids.add(result['id'])
    return ids


def get_all_ids_from_index(index, num_dimensions, namespace=""):
    #print(index.describe_index_stats())
    num_vectors = index.describe_index_stats(
    )["total_vector_count"]#[namespace]['vector_count']
    all_ids = set()
    while len(all_ids) < num_vectors:
        print("Length of ids list is shorter than the number of total vectors...")
        input_vector = np.random.rand(num_dimensions).tolist()
        print("creating random vector...")
        ids = get_ids_from_query(index, input_vector)
        print("getting ids from a vector query...")
        all_ids.update(ids)
        print("updating ids set...")
        print(f"Collected {len(all_ids)} ids out of {num_vectors}.")

    return all_ids

index_name = "langchain-demo"
index = pinecone.Index(index_name)
all_ids = get_all_ids_from_index(index, num_dimensions=1536, namespace="")
print(list(all_ids))

# https://docs.pinecone.io/docs/manage-data
index.fetch(list(all_ids))
```

Acknowledgment 
https://community.pinecone.io/t/how-to-retrieve-list-of-ids-in-an-index/380/11

Answer (score 1):

**Update: 8.12.2023**

```
pip3 install pinecone-client
```

```
import numpy as np
import pinecone

pinecone = Client(api_key=YOUR_API_KEY, region=REGION_OF_VECTORSTORE)
pinecone_index = pinecone.Index("your_index_name")


def get_ids_from_query(index,input_vector):
  print("searching pinecone...")
  results = index.query(
    top_k=10000,
    include_values=False,
    include_metadata=False,
    vector=input_vector,
  )
  ids = set()
  for result in results['matches']:

    ids.add(result.id)
  return ids

def get_all_ids_from_index(index, num_dimensions, namespace=""):
  num_vectors = index.describe_index_stats()
  num_vectors = num_vectors.namespaces[namespace].vector_count
  all_ids = set()
  while len(all_ids) < num_vectors:
    print("Length of ids list is shorter than the number of total vectors...")
    input_vector = np.random.rand(num_dimensions).tolist()
    print("creating random vector...")
    ids = get_ids_from_query(index,input_vector)
    print("getting ids from a vector query...")
    all_ids.update(ids)
    print("updating ids set...")
    print(f"Collected {len(all_ids)} ids out of {num_vectors}.")

  return all_ids

all_ids = get_all_ids_from_index(pinecone_index, num_dimensions=1536, namespace=YOUR_NAMESPACE)
print(all_ids)
```

**Acknowledgment**
Thanks a lot to @pandas https://stackoverflow.com/a/77000409/1766764 for sharing your solution.

Comment: missing `import pinecone` above but cannot edit